# Covariance matrix of infinite normal random variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Lets say that X is a normally distributed random variable with $\sigma_X = \lim_{a\to\infty} a$ and $E[X] = 0$. Lets say that Y is a normally distributed random variable with $\sigma_Y = \lim_{a\to\infty} 1/a$ and $E[Y] = 0$. What is the joint distribution covariance matrix of X and Y.

Comment: Could you explain what does it mean $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}a$?

Comment: I just mean that the standard deviation of x is infinity and the standard deviation of y is 0. Since that is ambiguous I am saying that the standard deviation of x is approaching infinity and the standard deviation of y is approaching the reciprocal of that at the same rate.

Comment: but what is a normal distribution with standard deviation equals to infinity? Probably you should fix your notation to something like this: Given $X_n$ is a sequence of independent normally distributed variables with $\sigma_n$, s.t. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sigma_n =  \infty$...

Comment: No, X and Y are just scalar normal random variables. The covariance matrix is 2 by 2 with $/Sigma_X^2$ and $/Sigma_Y^2$ on  the  diagonals. I just need to know the correlation coefficient to make the covariance matrix.

Comment: There is no such thing as normal variable with $\sigma = \infty$.

Comment: Of coarse there is ... take the limit of the PDF as sigma approaches to infinity. You will see that you get a uniform distribution with limits at plus and minus infinity.

Comment: In other words it is the x-axis

Comment: Seems that you just know better than I do. Good luck with the problem :)